# Is it possible to study in China without knowing Chinese?

Tags: graduate-admissions, language, china

Is it possible to enroll into and complete a graduate school in China while having only English language skills, without speaking Chinese at all? In particular, I am interested in (theoretical) physics.

Comment: I would note that English is the de facto international language of physics, to the point where any practicing Chinese physicist will be proficient in English. Many Chinese graduate students receive at least some of their instruction in English. So you can do physics research in China without knowing Chinese. But _living_ in China without knowing Chinese is a different matter altogether. (I don't recommend it.)

Comment: No way. You couldn't even order at McDonald or KFC without knowing Chinese CHARACTERS let alone spoken chinese

Comment: @MathNewb Actually... [you can](http://i.pbase.com/u17/bmcmorrow/upload/39185854.shanghaijan05312.JPG). IF you say you want a Hamburger and a Coca Cola in English, they will get it for you. The words for most fast food are bastardized. Even KFC is pronounced Ken Ta2 Ji1 (literally rhymes with Kentucky!).

Comment: Why live in China if you don't wish to interact with the locals?

Comment: @DavidZ *“any practicing Chinese physicist will be proficient in English”* — from my experience, I have to disagree with that, for any reasonable value of “proficient”.

Comment: @xebtl well, if your experience includes Chinese physicists who are not proficient in English, I will have to defer to that. All the Chinese physicists I've worked with _are_ proficient in English.

Comment: @DavidZ So has the only one I have worked with, but I have heard some others speak English such that I could not have worked with them for lack of a common language.  Not to blame them, I am sure learning English coming from Chinese is difficult.

Comment: The point is just that the level of English proficiency implied by being a working physicist (even a successful one) is, in my experience, quite modest.  That concerns talks, meetings in person, but also papers in peer-reviewed and copy-edited (?) journals.  (And of course it concerns people from all over, not just the Chinese!)

Answer (score 23):

If you include Hong Kong as part of China, the answer is Yes but limited to Hong Kong. English is an official language of Hong Kong. Universities in Hong Kong all use English as the media of teaching and the common language for research is English. No Physics courses are taught in languages other than English and no faculty members are not proficient in English. See [this official website](http://www.grad.edu.hk/grad/) for reference. The best are University of Hong Kong, The Chinese University of Hong Kong and The Hong Kong University of Science and Technology.

Otherwise the choices are limited to those high-ranking universities in China such as Peking University and Tsinghua University. In Tsinghua, most faculty members use English for publication purpose but not at all for communications in research. Most teaching and administration stuff are in Chinese. So you have to learn chinese at least in conversational level to survive a Phd there.

Answer (score 12):

Absolutely. Here is just [one example](http://www.cgeschina.com/beihang-university/programs/masters/masters-physics-beihang-university/).

There are many trans-national programs all over Asia (China, Hong Kong, Vietnam, Myanmar, etc.). Many of these programs are from partner universities in the UK or the US (and other countries). In these programs, the language of instruction and assessment is English. I teach in one such program (not the one linked above and it is related to business, not physics).

Can you get by without being able to communicate in the local language? That really depends on you. For example, if you are a social person you will really need to be able to communicate in the local language. While everyone (staff, faculty, students) at the university (in your department) will speak English others outside the school often struggle (as you would likely struggle picking up Chinese if you lived in the west).

If you are the kind of person who prefers isolation, then the local language is not so critical. Depending on where your city, you can usually find stores where you can buy most of the food you like (that is, western food) and even a place which will rent to you.

Some schools may well require you to learn the local language. The link above clearly shows it is offered (and you should take advantage of it). If you want to actively avoid learning Chinese, then you need to make sure the school you select does not require it. A quick email should sort that out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I truly need this info from a Westerner in Asia.

Comment: @scaaahu You only need to ask. :-)

Answer (score 10):

As an academic who has traveled to quite a few places where I had no idea (despite some study) of the ambient language, but/and also to quite a few places where I *did* have an adequate idea of the ambient language...

... and in contrast to the sort of wishful thinking that, for example, leads some tourists to say "oh, everyone speaks English there"... and leads some academics and business people to claim that English is the universal language of ... :

The psychological/cognitive load/burden of disconnectedness from the environment (apart from jokes about starving because one cannot ask for food) is highly non-trivial.

To be in a bubble for a week or so is maybe-tolerable, but for a year or more... I'd not do it. Either find within yourself the incentive to learn the language at least to the level of an 8-year-old, or don't go. The quasi-intellectual, quasi-independent-of-environment pose that has some mythological cachet is not good, in my experience. The people who fare best, in all ways, are those positively *interested* in the ambient language... and the culture depicted in it, etc.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think so, I am a medical student at China and it is compulsory for us to take Chinese Language. My friends doing their post-graduate degree already know Chinese, so I think it was a requirenment to apply.
Other than that, there are some universities which take Chinese into account but without having it in the actual degree. So just to help you while you're staying at China.

Comment: Would you tell us how much Chinese language do you need in order to live in China (such as shopping foods, taking bus transportation, etc)? Would you think one year Chinese language learning class would be enough? or more than 1 year? Thank you for your answer! I have  been waiting for somebody having your background to tell us.

Comment: Sure. You only need simple Chinese base, here they teach us the basic life simple things (buying, selling, greetings, communication easily, etc...) and I do study it alone in my spare time. One year of Chinese language is perfect and I don't think you'll need more, plus, you'll get used to it as you live here for couple of years. You're welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:**
Yes for other majors. Probably not for PhD in physics (you need to search).

**Long answer:**
Over the past ten years, many university from US and UK launch joint institution, ranging from summer language program to university with PhD program, in China with local universities. You could search for NYU shanghai, Duke kunshan, Michigan shanghai, Nottingham Ningbo, Xi'an Jiaotong-Liverpool University etc (The words you do not recognize are name of cities where the university is located in China, except the last one since I forgot where it is).

The good news is that English is the official communication language in those colleges.

Another good news is that they welcome (truly) international students, since almost all the students are Chinese.

Something you may not be interested in:
I do not know where the OP comes from. If OP comes from Africa, Chinese government provide special program with language program for those who can not speak Chinese.

**Comment on comment:**
What most Chinese people speak and their English language skills are irrelevant to the question. Most of the time you would communicate with your professors and fellows, other than some random guys on street.

Comment: Well... All I'm saying is that if you study in a foreign country then inevitably you will have to talk with the locals at some points. It makes your life considerably harder if you don't speak Chinese. It's not like doing a PhD is not already hard enough...

Comment: While the last paragraph of the answer may be _technically_ correct, in that it may be _possible_ to live in China without ever talking to anyone other than your colleagues at the university, it's a lousy way to live. I consider it highly misleading at best to say that it's irrelevant what most Chinese people speak.

Comment: That is a minor problem but not a difficulty that actually prevent OP pursuing degree in China. If it is worth mention, I would argue learning how to eat Chinese food everyday is important, since OP is inevitably eat Chinese food (almost) everyday. It makes your life considerably harder if you don't eat Chinese food.

Comment: Ok, ok. The language skill of OP would not improved after he come to China, and eventually he dies miserably several days later because he cannot speak Chinese with staff in cafe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Reading your answer, it is unclear for me why you mention that the physics major needs knowledge of local language in your short answer.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your home country, you'll probably end up with a scholarship.
Most foreigners coming to an average run of the mill Chinese university would qualify for such. It would be a feather in the cap of XXX Agricultural Normal University to have you as an honored graduate student, so much so they would fork out $$$ for you to come there.

www.csc.edu.cn is an amazing portal for higher education in China and can search by 
"English-taught" programs.  I'm sure there's one for you, China is a large place, many cities and many universities.  And there's Hong Kong (and Macau) to go to for English taught programs at a higher price.

Many a student have come to the land of China with zero Chinese but stuck it out and made friends and money.  Inevitably, you'll pick up Chinese along the way I'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

I am a postdoc living in China since almost 2 years. I came here without knowing any one phrase in Chinese.

My answer to the question is: **No, it is currently impossible to study in Mainland China for years in a row without learning any form of Chinese.**

Apart from the fact that few locals are proficient in English, almost all daily, and probably administrative communication runs in Chinese, and automated digital translators will not provide always a satisfactory solution. Surely local students and deputies will help in the beginning but after a certain time they will become less accessible.

Moreover, Chinese comes as a package: one cannot truly learn the culture without understanding some of the language and vice-versa. Therefore interacting below the surface with locals will depend on learning some of the language even if not at any functional level.

I cannot speak for Macau, Hong Kong, or Taiwan as I have not lived in these areas. I suspect it should be doable in these places, particularly in Hong Kong.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will meet some difficulties at first. You will find difficult to  listen to the class and do homework in Chinese. But at Chinese university, usually you can find Engish text book in the library and your classmates will be willing to teach you Chinese. Teacher's PPT sometimes uses English too. As long as you study hard, you will be accustomed to.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, possible, but I highly recommend you against it.

Generally, US students are welcome to universities or research institutes in China, especially the top ones (Tsinghua U, Peking U, SJTU, ...) in Beijing and Shanghai. You would get used to everyday life in less than a semester, without learning much Chinese.

However, physics is not a typical major to do so in this case. Top universities have many young professors with their PhD or postdoc done in US, as well as part time professors from top US universities. But there's almost no pure English physics graduate program in main land China.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, one can enroll in some graduate programs in China that are taught in English， and in some cases, even if the program is not offered in English, some courses may still be taught in English, so there might be a possibility to still accept you. This will depend on the university and programs. For example, at my university some general undergraduate and master degree courses offered to Chinese students are taught in Chinese while some others are taught in English (it depends on the professor and topic). Besides, I know some Vietnamese Master degree students who did a master in computer science in Changsha without speaking Chinese... and another doing a PhD in computer science in Harbin without speaking Chinese. And there is some post-doc researchers and professors who also do not speak Chinese. I don't know for physics but if you look around, I think you can find. But of course, if you know some basic Chinese, you will better enjoy the life in China. At least, you should try to learn how to buy stuff, ask for the price of something or ask for directions using Chinese, to make your life easier!   There is also some universities in China, where taking some Chinese training is mandatory for graduate studies. For example, in Xi'an Jiatong Univ. some students told me that for PhD they had to take 8 months of Chinese class on the first year. But in the end, they found that it was useful for daily life.  Also if you speak Chinese, I heard that you may more easily get scholarships from the Chinese government perhaps for your studies.